# How to fix this (Filter program) using batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

**I have a text file named `file.txt` Which contains,**

```
Combo: testing123mail@gmail.com:password
As Combo: 
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@gmail.com:ajfbdf
some text here
some more text here
As Combo: hadvsfhia@ahfjbadj.com:password@1
some random text here
iloveu@gmail.com:passypassyword123
goldenmammy@hotmail.com:youtube123
```

**I am running the below code, to filter only `mail:pass` from the above text file `file.txt`**

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('type file.txt^|find "As Combo:"') do >>mail.txt echo %%a
for /f "tokens=2" %%b in ('type file.txt^|find "Combo:"') do >>mail.txt echo %%b
for /f "tokens=1" %%c in ('type file.txt^|find ":"') do >>mail.txt echo %%c
```

**Expected Output in `mail.txt`,**

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@gmail.com:ajfbdf
hadvsfhia@ahfjbadj.com:password@1
testing123mail@gmail.com:password
iloveu@gmail.com:passypassyword123
goldenmammy@hotmail.com:youtube123
```

**But, am getting actual output is,**

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@gmail.com:ajfbdf
hadvsfhia@ahfjbadj.com:password@1
testing123mail@gmail.com:password
Combo:
Combo:
Combo:
As
As
iloveu@gmail.com:passypassyword123
goldenmammy@hotmail.com:youtube123
```

**Note:** The mail id and passwords will differ in different text files. Above given mail id and passwords are typed by me randomly for example.

Comment: I recommend you using regex in vbscript to extract such data.

Comment: Here is a [Demo with regex](https://regex101.com/r/3woYZ9/1) to show you how this kind of data can be extracted, so, if you want that i will post you a solution in vbscript, just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24533329) your question and add the tag vbscript !

Comment: Why not add find for `@` as well seeing as you extract email addresses all containing it.

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58777829/collecting-parts-of-text-from-a-text-file-after-given-tags)